# Font Alternative missing in Gimp

Tags: fonts, gimp

I'm running gimp 2.8.22 on Linux Mint.  I've installed a font family (Montserrat) and all font alternatives appear in the gnome-font-viewer but some alternatives are missing in Gimp. Specifically I need to use Montserrat-Black but it isn't available.  How do I make Gimp use this font alternative?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a naming inconsistency with the font.
There are separate .otf files for MontserratAlternatives-Black,  Montserrat-Bold and MontserratAlternatives-Bold  But no OTF file for Montserrat-Heavy.   However the font presents in the applications (Both Gimp and Inkscape) as Montserrat Heavy.